# Matlab Question: How to compute all partitions of [1,2,...,n] for a fixed number of parts?

Tags: combinatorics, matlab

For example: [1,2,3,4] and k=3 parts should yield

[1],[2],[3,4]

[1],[3],[2,4]

[1],[4],[2,3]

[2],[3],[1,4]

[2],[4],[1,3]

[3],[4],[1,2]

as an output.

For k=2 with the same set we would get

[1],[2,3,4]

[2],[1,3,4]

[3],[1,2,4]

[4],[1,2,3]

[1,2],[3,4]

[1,3],[2,4]

[1,4],[2,3]

instead.

Can anyone give me some advice here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24185-partitions)?

Answer (score 0):

Stirling numbers of second kind: $S(n,k)$ is the number of partitions of an $n$-element set into $k$ nonempty pairwise disjoint subsets. There is a recursion for computing these numbers: $S(n,1)=1=S(n,n)$ and $S(n,k+1) = k\cdot S(n,k) + S(n,k-1)$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! This would give me the information about the number of possible subsets. My remaining problem is it to calculate these explicitly. Do you also know how to realize that?

Answer (score 0):

I will solve problem for $n=4$ special case. I hope that you can find the solution method for bigger values of $n$.

For $k=1$, there is only $1$ partition: $[1234]$

For $k=2$, there are two groups that $[ab],[cd]$ and $[a],[bcd]$. In the case $[ab],[cd]$: $\dbinom{4}{2} \cdot \dbinom{2}{1}$. But $[ab],[cd]$ and $[cd],[ab]$ are identical. So we have to divide by $2!$, hence $\dfrac{1}{2!}\dbinom{4}{2}=3$. Now in the case $[a],[bcd]$: $\dbinom{4}{1} \cdot \dbinom{3}{3}=4$. Sum of these $3 + 4 = 7$

For $k=3$, there are $[a],[b],[cd]$ partitions. Therefore $\dbinom{4}{1} \cdot \dbinom{3}{1} \cdot \dbinom{2}{2}$. But $[a],[b],[cd]$ and $[b],[a],[cd]$ gives identical partitions. Thus we have to divide by $2!$ and hence $\dfrac{1}{2!}\dbinom{4}{1} \cdot \dbinom{3}{1}=6$.

For $k=4$, there are $[a],[b],[c],[d]$ partitions. We get $\dbinom{4}{1} \cdot \dbinom{3}{1}\cdot \dbinom{2}{1} \cdot \dbinom{1}{1}$. But permutating of $[a],[b],[c],[d]$  are identical. Thus we have to divide by $4!$ and we find $ \dfrac{1}{4!}\dbinom{4}{1} \cdot \dbinom{3}{1}\cdot \dbinom{2}{1}=1$.

**Note:** Number of total partitions is $1+7+6+1=15$.